# Firebase Audience with time events criteria

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I would like to define an audience in Firebase based on last time an event was fired. For example, I would like to reengage users who did not open the app (event: *app_open*) last 30 days.

I've been trying to define an audience based on this criteria with no success.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the Firebase Notifications panel? If so, what is giving you problems?

Comment: Yes, I went to Analytics > Audiences and created a new one called "Inactive users". I select "app_open" event, but I don't see anything to filter based on where was the last time it was registered

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that as of now. However if you export to BigQuery you could define the audience here (and end-up with a list of player in that audience). If you wanted to target them with notification it would require you to store somewhere in your server the list of GCM token (for iOS/Android) and then handle the communication with GCM servers to send the push.
It's not ideal, but as of today it's the only solution I know about.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid using an external process to do this. Hope someone in Firebase team read this and add this to their roadmap :)

Comment: Does anyone know whether it is now possible to do it in the firebase notifications panel ? Or it may be possible to define a time frame (for instance last 7 days) when we define an audience in firebase analytics ? I cannot find it...

Comment: @Alex9494 Still not possible. However now you can use User Property when targetting users in Firebase Notifications (link to the doc https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6394759#segments )
If you have a user property which is, for instance, last logging timestamp (epoch format), you can easily send a push to every user that have that user property lower than "now-3days in ms".

Comment: Great idea :) Thank you !

Comment: @Sistr How is that done in the Console? When creating an audience you can just do some property like "last_opened" but can't compare it to now() or some other function. You can only enter some value...would appreciate any advice thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Background**

Earlier, one of the biggest limitations was that, once a user was placed into an audience, they could never leave. But that has changed with the new dynamic audience features that were announced at the Firebase Summit in October 2018. With dynamic audiences, users will join an audience when they meet the criteria for it, but also leave that audience when they no longer belong to the audience using a feature called 'Membership Duration'.

**Feature**

Here's how `Membership Duration` works: Your app will continually evaluating whether or not your users belong to each one of these audiences that you've defined, and is "renewing" your user to audiences that they've qualified for. What this duration field will do is look at a user's last "I've qualified for an audience" time and remove them from the audience if that time was longer than the current membership duration.

**Solution**

In your case, you just need to add a Membership Duration of 30 days to the audience with `app_open` event to get the required audience.

[image: FirebaseAnalyticsScreen]

*Please note that audience populating starts only after a custom audience is created and doesn't use previous data.*